# Slick animate when moving past the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to make a carousel like this:

[image]

I have used these settings:

```
{
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    centerMode: true,
    event: {
        init: scope.init
    }
}
```

This seems to get the actual animation working fine. The next part (which is the bit causing me issues) is trying to get the "**dot**" and text to animate in size an colour. Does anyone know how I might go about doing that?
I am trying to use the **swipe** method but the issue is working out which is the item closest to the center as I am swiping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

## Update

So I have managed to do part of this.
I added the init callback to the options and added some code to work out the position of the center element and it's size.

```
// Extend our scope
angular.extend(scope, {
    init: function (e, slick) {

        // Get our dragable element
        var sizes = scope.options.sizes,
            draggableElement = element[0].getElementsByClassName('draggable')[0],
            centerElement = draggableElement.getElementsByClassName('slick-center')[0].childNodes[0];

        // Set the active dimensions and margins
        centerElement.style.width = sizes.finish + 'px';
        centerElement.style.height = sizes.finish + 'px';
        centerElement.style.borderRadius = sizes.finish / 2 + 'px';
        centerElement.style.marginTop = '0';
        centerElement.style.marginBottom = '0';

        slick.$list.on('touchmove.slick mousemove.slick', function () {
            _resizePoint(slick, this, sizes);
        });
    }
});

// Extend our options
angular.extend(scope.options, {
    event: {
        init: scope.init
    },
    sizes: {
        start: 18,
        finish: 50
    }
});


// Resizes the point
var _resizePoint = function (slick, container, sizes) {

    // Get our actual Width
    var containerPadding = parseInt(container.style.paddingLeft),
        containerWidth = container.offsetWidth - containerPadding * 2;

    // If we have a swipe left
    if (slick.swipeLeft) {

        // Get our slide index
        var center = containerWidth / 2,
            left = -slick.swipeLeft > 0 ? -slick.swipeLeft : slick.swipeLeft,
            distance = left + center,
            index = Math.floor(distance / slick.slideWidth);

        // Get the active element
        var activeElement = container.childNodes[0].childNodes[index].childNodes[0];

        // Get our start point
        var half = slick.slideWidth / 2,
            start = center - half,
            position = (index * slick.slideWidth) - left;

        // Get our dimensions 
        var startDimension = sizes.start,
            finishDimension = sizes.finish,
            startMargin = (finishDimension - startDimension) / 2

        // Get the percentage in relation to the center
        var percent = (center - position) / half,
            directionalPercent = position > start ? percent : 2 - percent,
            dimension = startMargin + ((finishDimension - startMargin) * directionalPercent),
            marginPercent = 1 - directionalPercent,
            margin = startMargin * marginPercent;

        // Apply our sizes to our element
        activeElement.style.width = dimension + 'px';
        activeElement.style.height = dimension + 'px';
        activeElement.style.borderRadius = dimension / 2 + 'px';
        activeElement.style.marginTop = margin + 'px';
        activeElement.style.marginBottom = margin + 'px';
    }
};
```

This works while dragging, but when **focusOnSelect** is true, click an item does not resize it. Also using the navigational arrows doesn't work and finally when you let go of drag, when it moves to the center, that doesn't resize either.

I was hoping to override the **animateSlide** method to insert my code, but my code works on the current items position and I don't think that will work with **animateSlide**.

I have added a bounty now, because I assume someone can help me with this.

### Update 2

I have created a codepen to illustrate my issue.

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/vKPyxE?editors=1010

If you drag left or right, you can see that the "dot" increases and decreases in size. But if you click any of the dots it just moves straight there with not size change.

I hope that explains my issue :)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue, can you clarify what you mean by "trying to get the dot and text to animate in size and colour"?

Comment: so they look like the git I attached.

Comment: git = gif. I assume this means you can't help?

Comment: @r3plica, can you provide a jsfiddle of the current working version?

Comment: Im with Dekel, it'll help a lot if we can see a functional demo

Comment: Added a codepen :)

Comment: @r3plica, just to make sure - you want the dots to animate **during** the drag (both color and size)? Or is it ok that the change(color/size) will be only after the drop (or when click on some other dot)?

Comment: I already have it working during the drag. The issue is when I click a dot or press the navigation arrows. I need it to animate in the same way (if you look at the _resizePoint method you can see how I work out how to resize the dot).

Comment: During the drag there is a change in the size, but no change in the color. Do you need that as well?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't added the colour change because I just wanted to get an example up :)

Answer (score 4):

Check  [**this codepane demo**](http://codepen.io/hareshvidja/pen/vKrBLq)

Here I have made changes in CSS file and JS file

In CSS file I have added CSS properties for animation and make bigger circle on current slide.

```
.slick-slider .slick-slide .slider-point
{
  transition:  1s ease-in;
}
```

And in JS file I have removed some of your code and added callback of slick sliders based on Event section in [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
angular.module('slick', ['slickCarousel']).controller('MainController', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}).directive('pkSlider', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
return {
    restrict: 'A',

    scope: {
        items: '=pkSlider',
        options: '='
    },

    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/pk-slider.html',

    link: function(scope, element){

        $timeout(function(){
            // Extend our options
            angular.extend(scope.options, {
                event: {
                // init: scope.init,
                init: function(event, slick){
                    // let's do this after we init the banner slider
                    sizes=slick.options.sizes;
                    var margin=(sizes.finish-sizes.start)/2;
                    $(slick.$slides[slick.initials.currentSlide]).find('.slider-point').css({
                        width: sizes.finish + 'px',
                        height: sizes.finish + 'px',
                        borderRadius: sizes.finish / 2 + 'px',
                        marginTop: '0',
                        marginBottom: '0'
                    });    
                },
                beforeChange: function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

                    sizes=slick.options.sizes;

                    var margin=(sizes.finish-sizes.start)/2;

                    $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('.slider-point').css({
                        width: sizes.start + 'px',
                        height: sizes.start + 'px',
                        borderRadius: sizes.start / 2 + 'px',
                        marginTop: margin+'px',
                        marginBottom: margin+'px'
                    });

                    $(slick.$slides[nextSlide]).find('.slider-point').css({
                        width: sizes.finish + 'px',
                        height: sizes.finish + 'px',
                        borderRadius: sizes.finish / 2 + 'px',
                        marginTop: '0',
                        marginBottom: '0'
                    })
                }
            },
            sizes: {
            start: 18,
            finish: 50
            }
        });
    });
}};
}]);
```

Comment: I see what you have done, but that isn't what I am after. As a point scrolls past the center of the screen, it needs to animate in size and colour also.

Comment: I have modified code http://codepen.io/hareshvidja/pen/vKrBLq I hope it as per your requirement...

Comment: @r3plica, I have modified code for passed callback events in slider initialize configutaion in javascript code.

Comment: Hey Haresh, it still doesn't work as I need it to. If you drag from the furthest point on the right to point 3, you will see that point 2 does not animate in size when passing the center. It should, also if we could see 3 on the screen and clicked it, 2 should change size as it passes the center.

Comment: @r3plica, ahh, i see what you say, circle it not animating when it move from last point to first point and vice e versa, I have checked with inspect element tool for this case. slick slider plugin moving all elements so it create some strange conflicts.

Comment: @r3plica, Haresh has done more than enough for an so question, what you are asking is custom JS development coz the library you chose doesn't add any classes as the elements pass through the center... Only when the swiping stops, a class is added to the active slide in center, until then it's not easy to apply any styles to it...

Comment: I'd recommend you to hire a JS developer for writing a JS library for you, which adds `active` class even as the element passes through center... Once you do that you'll see that Haresh has done all the stuff for ya, for which he was paid nothing...

Comment: clearly you have not looked at my example or my code. Haresh has provided what he thinks is the solution, but it is no better than my own original code. At least my code actually does work when dragging. The code he removed actually performed a function. Not only that, the only thing he has actually done is add a CSS transition time and used jquery selectors where I had not. That is the only difference. If you have nothing constructive to say, don't say anything.

Comment: @r3plica, I am understanding your concern, but currently you have updated code in your codepan (http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/vKPyxE?editors=1010) it is very different then you have provided and asked about solution before. because of Codepan not generate different url for each revision as fiddle. I have done many difference in code rather than CSS transition. like event callback integration.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of the CSS3 [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) transform to grow the size of the bubble to however big you want it like so (applying the style directly to the `.slick-center` class of course):

```
.slick-slide.slick-center .slider-point {
  -webkit-transform: scale( 2.5 );
     -moz-transform: scale( 2.5 );
       -o-transform: scale( 2.5 );
      -ms-transform: scale( 2.5 );
          transform: scale( 2.5 );
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/andresilich/pen/jAREmO

Comment: same as Haresh, this is fine for .slick-center but not for each dot that goes past the center. Every dot that goes past the center should have the animation whether it is clicked or dragged. If there are 9 dots on the screen and the furthest do away is clicked. Each dot that animates past the center should animate in size and colour as it passes.

Comment: @Andres, Your solution is very interesting and works very well with scalling current point by 2.5x, I was going provide same solution as you done but I see in code there is dimensions of circle is configurable